# How do you group Eclipse SWT Widgets together under a common header/label?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt

I am developing a Multi Page Editor for Eclipse and would like to group common features and functionality into groups under a common header/label. How would I code this in my Eclipse Plugin Editor code?

Please check out this image:

[image]

How do I create those groups, "General Information", "Plug-in Content", etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor in the image is using [Eclipse Forms](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/forms.htm). The groups are created using [`Section`s](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/forms_controls_section.htm). In normal SWT you would use [`Group`s](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/forms.htm) instead.